# Unable to install SASS on Windows machine using ruby

Tags: ruby, sass

I have just install Ruby Installer 2.3(x64), on my Windows machine as I wanted it for SASS.
On typing
`gem install sass` in "Start command prompt with Ruby" , it shows the error:

> 'gem' is not recognised.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ruby -v` on the command line. If it throws up an error, try adding ruby to path. To add this:

1. Go to `Computer`.
2. Click on `properties` at the top left
3. Click on `Advanced System Settings`
4. Click on `Environment Variables` at the bottom right of the popup
5. Open another tab and look in the C: drive to find Ruby is installed. It should be `C:\Ruby23-x64\bin` or so. Copy the path.
6. Go back to the environment variable and click on `PATH`.
7. Choose `edit` option and add the a semi-colon `;` before pasting the ruby path copied.

**Note**

Your windows machine may be slightly different. I am using Surface Pro 3 which runs on Windows 8.